# Identify a movie from the 80s with a crystal bowl full of red berries

Tags: story-identification, movie

There’s an American film where a young girl has to try and save her brother by going through a maze and eating red berries from a crystal bowl.

Comment: Is this _[Labyrinth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labyrinth_(1986_film))_ (1986)? If not, can you tell us a little more about the film? For example, roughly how old was the brother? Who or what did he need to be saved from? And were there magical creatures in the film? A castle? Anything else you can think of?

Comment: I suppose [*Pan's Labyrinth*](https://mealenscene.wordpress.com/2015/03/07/pans-labyrinth-2006-grapes-innocence/) would be too recent, although it technically has her eat berries (grapes) from a table with crystal dishes.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Pan's Labyrinth is not an American film, as stated in the question.

Answer (score 11):

***Pan's Labyrinth* (2006)**

The movie isn't American, but Spanish-Mexican (but undoubtedly dubbed for American audiences). However:

- It is about a young girl trying to save her baby brother
- She has to enter the eponymous labyrinth
- There, she takes and eats some red grapes from a crystal bowl

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems a fair match to me. I suspect OP has conflated this scene with one from *Labyrinth.*

Answer (score 9):

Is this ***[Labyrinth](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091369/)*** (1986)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labyrinth_(1986_film)):

> *Labyrinth* is a 1986 musical fantasy film directed by Jim Henson with George Lucas as executive producer. Based on conceptual designs by Brian Froud, the film was written by Terry Jones, and many of its characters are played by puppets produced by Jim Henson's Creature Shop. **The film stars Jennifer Connelly as 16-year-old Sarah and David Bowie as Jareth, the Goblin King. In *Labyrinth*, Sarah embarks on a quest to reach the center of an enormous, otherworldly maze to rescue her infant half-brother Toby, whom she wished away to Jareth.**

A teenage girl's baby brother is kidnapped by a Goblin King from another world. In order to rescue her brother, she must find her way through the Goblin King's labyrinth in order to reach his castle. I don't recall her eating red berries from a crystal bowl, but she is tricked into eating an enchanted peach that sends her into a dream of the Goblin King's design. The Goblin King also plays with small glass spheres alot, and uses them as part of his spells.

Answer (score 2):

*[The Hugga Bunch](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0173915/)* (1985)?

> A girl travels through her mirror into HuggaLand to find a way to keep her grandmother, the only one who knows how to hug, young.

It has the red berries being collected in a crystal bowl with a lid

[image]

My wife used to love this movie.She showed it to me and I find it incredibly creepy.

Comment: A good find. I've taken the liberty of adding a screenshot

Comment: The OP's description mentions that the main character has to save her brother by going through a maze. Are those elements present in this film?